# Разделить строку на подстроки с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Сценарий на входе получает строки, каждая из которых завершается парой круглых скобок с произвольным текстом между ними. Требуется отделить этот текст между скобками от всего остального текста строки, разбив таким образом изначальную строку на две подстроки.

Например, после обработки строки

```
"Небольшая группа демонстрантов, протестующих у (какого-либо) учреждения (5 букв)"
```

на выходе должно получиться две подстроки:

```
"Небольшая группа демонстрантов, протестующих у (какого-либо) учреждения"
```

и

```
"(5 букв)"
```

Скобки в целом значения не имеют, но во второй подстроке от них было-бы желательно избавиться сразу

Проблема заключается в том, что круглые скобки в тексте строки могут встречаться более одного раза.
Помогите составить шаблон регулярного выражения.
Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

In [11]: s
Out[11]: 'Небольшая группа демонстрантов, протестующих у (какого-либо) учреждения (5 букв)'

In [12]: re.search(r'(.*)\s+\((.*)\)\s*$', s).groups()
Out[12]:
('Небольшая группа демонстрантов, протестующих у (какого-либо) учреждения',
 '5 букв')
```